# Where should i store authentication token in android

Tags: android

Where do I need to store the authentication token which will be submitted with each request in an Android application? I'm asking for a secure storage location, for example iphone has keychain, is there an equivalent service in Android? Is storing in shared preferences secure or not?

Answer (score 0):

In Android 4.3+ there is something called AndoridKeystore which is roughly equivalent to iOS key chain. [Here](http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/credential-storage-enhancements-android-43.html)'s a good blog write up of it and official [API sample project](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicAndroidKeyStore/index.html).

In general if your create your shared preferences with `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` they are only accessible by your application (or other app signed by your key). However if the device is rooted they the user and any app could potentially read your app's private shared preferences.

I helped create and maintain a library called [secure-preferences](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences) to obfuscate key and values that are stored in the shared preferences to make it harder for attackers and require then to reverse engineer the app (although that's not rocket science). A good alternative to secure-preferences is [CWAC-prefs](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-prefs) by Mark Murphy which is backed by SQLcipher.