# Remembering Password for a Sign Up page in an Android App

Tags: android

I want to create a Sign Up page in an Android App, where Username and password field need to added.
The trick is that there is a checkbox too, if the checkBox is selected then the app 
should remember the password!! , for a given userName

Can someone help me out?

Comment: use `SharedPreferences` for details check http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Comment: an upvote will be really welcomed,Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your sign up page and save the names and password in a sharedpreference, by the `putString("key","value")`.. and add a checkbox and when the user clicks sign up button, check if the `checkbox.isChecked()`.. if its checked it should return true and put that too in your sharedpreference using the `putBoolean("key","value")`.. and whenever the login activity starts check the boolean value using `getBoolean("key","value")`.. if true automatically sign in..

EDIT 1:

registration screen

```
EditText name, password;
CheckBox cb;
Button b;
SharedPreferences sp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sp = getSharedPreferences("auth", 0);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Editor  e = sp.edit();
            e.putString("auth_name", name.getText().toString());
            e.putString("auth_pass", password.getText().toString());
            e.putBoolean("auth_status", cb.isChecked());
            e.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

login activity

```
EditText name, password;
Button b;
SharedPreferences sp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sp = getSharedPreferences("auth", 0);

    if(sp.getBoolean("auth_status", false)){  // the false stands for default value
        name.setText(sp.getString("auth_name", "elltz")); //default vaule is elltz
        password.setText(sp.getString("auth_pass", "elltz")); //default vaule is elltz
    }

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Log user in when he/she clicks

        }
    });
}
```

and here's the xml code.. same used for both registration and login

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:text="remember " />
</RelativeLayout>
```

that's it.. so copy paste and see if it works

Comment: Can you tell me the way of how to do it, I am not able to figure oyt how?? Please

Comment: sorry for taking  long give me 5 mins@AkshaySharma

Answer (score 0):

Use Shared Pref for the task. When the **checkbox** is checked, save it to appropriate Shared pref. When it's not then clear it.

**For example:**

When checkbox is checked, load your username and password to shared pref. But when its unchecked, don't load (Or may be clear it)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to use shared preferences, it is week point and can be hacked by simple device rooting.
See more info:

> In Android 4.3+ there is something called AndoridKeystore which is roughly equivalent to iOS key chain. Here's a good blog write up of it and official API sample project.
>
> In general if your create your shared preferences with
>   Context.MODE_PRIVATE they are only accessible by your application (or
>   other app signed by your key). However if the device is rooted they
>   the user and any app could potentially read your app's private shared
>   preferences.
>
> I helped create and maintain a library called secure-preferences to
>   obfuscate key and values that are stored in the shared preferences to
>   make it harder for attackers and require then to reverse engineer the
>   app (although that's not rocket science). A good alternative to
>   secure-preferences is CWAC-prefs by Mark Murphy which is backed by
>   SQLcipher.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19810011/232727).